# Приоритет загрузки данных jquery

Tags: html, jquery, json

Всех с новым годом, есть ссылка при нажатию на которую загружаются данные это:

1) JSON данные (post запрос)

2) Html форма (get запрос)

// загрузка HTML формы

```
function getProduct(){
    function loadContent() {
        $('.content').load("prod.html");

    }
}
```

//ajax запрос

```
function getAjaxProduct(val){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_one_product.php',
        data: {val},
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#title').text(response.title);
            $('#price').text(response.price);
            $('#date').text(response.date);

        }
    });
}
```

// получение данных

```
$(document).on('click', '#buy', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $(this).attr("value"); 

   getProduct();
    getAjaxProduct(val);
});
```

Как сделать, что бы сначала загружалась HTML а потом JSON ?

Comment: [load](https://api.jquery.com/load/). Вам нужно в `complete` вызвать свой `ajax`

Comment: Или использовать в функции loadContent $(document).ready(function() { или $(window).on('load', function () {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполнять загрузку данных в обработчике завершения загрузки разметки

```
function getProduct(val){
  function loadContent() {
    $('.content').load("prod.html", function() {
      getAjaxContent(val);
    });
  }
}
```

А лучше все делать асинхронно, а в последней выполнившейся функции заполнять данные

```
function fillData(response) {
  $('#title').text(response.title);
  $('#price').text(response.price);
  $('#date').text(response.date);
}

$(document).on('click', '#buy', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var val = $(this).attr("value"); 

  var contentLoaded = false;
  var data = null;
  $('.content').load("prod.html", function() {
    contentLoaded = true;
    if (data)
      fillData(data);
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: 'get_one_product.php',
    data: {val},
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (response) {
      data = response;
      if (contentLoaded)
        fillData(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: теперь работает как нужно=)